# Syncing OneNote does not work with Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, sync, microsoft-onenote-2013

I have Office 2013 both at home and at office and I am logged on to both machines. Now, when I want to sync some of the notes from Home and Office then I basically went to File> Settings>Sync but as soon as I do that it throws following error:

> We're sorry, something went wrong during sync. We'll try again later.
>   (Error code: 0x80004005)

I did some search online and it turned out that it may be the case when we are using two different versions for Office but my both clients are the same exact versions and the error code/Message just does not seem to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by one corrupted page or section.

If sync doesn't work, the best way is to create a brand new notebook and move pages over.

Move sections / pages bit by bit, then sync (F9 key), until you find out which section or page is causing the problem. Then deal with the problem page (e.g. copy the content out or delete it)